# PowerShell search XML file contents

Tags: xml, powershell

I am trying to search through an xml file that has multiple sections called Custom_ID for one in particular, i have been looking at this [site](https://www.thomasmaurer.ch/2010/06/powershell-parsing-xml-part-1/) which indicates I should be able to do a filter.

Once I have identified the section, I then need to retrieve Custom_ID_Shared_Reference.ID

I can get all of them by using

```
$Val = ([xml]$WD_UpdateAccount.Content).envelope.body.Get_Change_Other_IDs_Response.Response_Data.Change_Other_IDs.Change_Other_IDs_Data.Custom_Identification_Data.Custom_ID
```

I can see the values by looking at

```
$val.Custom_ID_Data.ID_Type_Reference.ID
```

But when I try to filter, I get no results.  I have tried various where-object -like -contains etc but I think its more likely Custom_ID_Data.ID_Type_Reference.ID bit I am doing wrong

```
$Val = ([xml]$WD_UpdateAccount.Content).envelope.body.Get_Change_Other_IDs_Response.Response_Data.Change_Other_IDs.Change_Other_IDs_Data.Custom_Identification_Data.Custom_ID | Where-Object {$_.Custom_ID_Data.ID_Type_Reference.ID -contains 'Active_Directory_Username'}
```

example of the xml

```
<wd:Custom_ID>
    <wd:Custom_ID_Reference>
        <wd:ID wd:type="WID">922a9f7f0412035621dd3baca7f23e21f10a</wd:ID>
    </wd:Custom_ID_Reference>
    <wd:Custom_ID_Data>
        <wd:ID>Kimi Raikkonen3</wd:ID>
        <wd:ID_Type_Reference>
            <wd:ID wd:type="WID">e60e1796143f501cdb08</wd:ID>
            <wd:ID wd:type="Custom_ID_Type_ID"
                >Active_Directory_Username</wd:ID>
        </wd:ID_Type_Reference>
    </wd:Custom_ID_Data>
    <wd:Custom_ID_Shared_Reference>
        <wd:ID wd:type="WID">aedd9ad02</wd:ID>
        <wd:ID wd:type="Custom_Identifier_Reference_ID"
            >CUSTOM_IDENTIFIER_REFERENCE-6-1</wd:ID>
    </wd:Custom_ID_Shared_Reference>
</wd:Custom_ID>
```

Any help appreciated, first time I have had to work with XML.

Comment: I get the xml error:  `Error: "'wd' is an undeclared prefix.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand all the node references in your code.  Working from the xml you've given, and putting in a fake namespace on line 1:

```
<wd:Custom_ID xmlns:wd="whatever">
```

```
[xml]$xml = get-content file.xml

$xml.custom_id | where { $_.custom_id_data.id_type_reference.id.'#text' -contains 
  'active_directory_username' }                                     


wd       Custom_ID_Reference Custom_ID_Data Custom_ID_Shared_Reference
--       ------------------- -------------- --------------------------
whatever Custom_ID_Reference Custom_ID_Data Custom_ID_Shared_Reference
```

The id object has both type and #text properties.

```
$xml.custom_id.custom_id_data.id_type_reference.id

type              #text
----              -----
WID               e60e1796143f501cdb08
Custom_ID_Type_ID Active_Directory_Username
```

Trying something with an xpath expression that gives the same result, sidestepping the namespace:

```
select-xml '//*[text()="Active_Directory_Username"]/../../..' file.xml | % node


wd       Custom_ID_Reference Custom_ID_Data Custom_ID_Shared_Reference
--       ------------------- -------------- --------------------------
whatever Custom_ID_Reference Custom_ID_Data Custom_ID_Shared_Reference
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I am effectively a 1 man band at the moment.  This did the trick for me.

where { $_.custom_id_data.id_type_reference.id.'#text' -contains 
  'active_directory_username' }

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
@(([xml]$WD_UpdateAccount.Content).envelope.body.Get_Change_Other_IDs_Response.Response_Data.Change_Other_IDs.Change_Other_IDs_Data.Custom_Identification_Data.Custom_ID) | Where-Object {$_.Custom_ID_Data.ID_Type_Reference.ID -contains 'Active_Directory_Username'}
```

...the extra `@()` wrapping converts the object to a base array-type which will allow the corresponding `Where-Object` to be able to understand what's being passed down the pipeline.

At it's core, the problem is the xml object type that is returned and that it isn't understood by `Where-Object`.

Comment: There's a '#text' property underneath 'ID' that has the text being searched for.